# No aparecen los datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario de registro conectado a una base de datos que se conecta perfectamente, cuando introduzco los datos y le doy a registrar, me sale el mensaje de "Registrado correctamente" pero cuando voy a phpMyAdmin, no se han guardado los datos en la base de datos..

**Formulario:**

```
<form class="caja-datos" method="post" action="">
<h3>Registro</h3>

<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="APELLIDO">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="USUARIO">
<br><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="passwordconfirmation" placeholder="REPITE LA CONTRASEÑA">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar">
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
    include("conexion.php");

     if(isset($_POST['registrar'])){

            if($_POST['nombre'] == '' or $_POST['apellido'] == '' or $_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['email'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['passwordconfirmation'] == ''){

         echo "Debe llenar todos los campos por favor.";

     }else{

     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
     $rec = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     $verificar = 0;

      while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($rec))
      {
          if($resultado->usuario == $_POST['usuario'])
          {
              $verificar = 1;
          }
      }

      if($verificar == 0)
      {
        if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['passwordconfirmation']) {


        $nom = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pw = $_POST['password'];


        $pw_en = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);



        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO usuarios ('nombre','apellido','usuario','email','password','passwordconfirmation') VALUES ('$nom','$apellido','$user','$email','$pw_en')");



         mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


                    echo "Te has registrado con exito.";

                            }else{
                                echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
                            }

                          }else{
                            echo "El nombre de usuario ya esta en nuestra base de datos, por favor prueba otro.";
                       }
         }
}
?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!. Ese query esta mal. Estas pidiendo para llenar 6  campos, pero solo le pasas 5. No recibis ningun error porque no estas controlando nada.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu SQL de inserción no funcionará: `INSERT INTO usuarios ('nombre','apellido','usuario','email','password','passwordconfirmation') VALUES ('$nom','$apellido','$user','$email','$pw_en')` tiene 6 columnas y 5 values. Además, no es necesario poner los nombres de columna entre comillas simples... Desde ya te advierto de que esa consulta es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Toma nota para que corrijas ese fallo más adelante o la seguridad de tu sistema podría estar comprometida tarde o temprano.

Comment: Ya esta arreglado, muchas gracias! No se como poner que ya esta solucionada la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Te falta poner la acción en el HTML

```html
<form class="caja-datos" method="post" action="NOMBREDETUPHP.php">
  <h3>Registro</h3>

  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="APELLIDO">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="USUARIO">
  <br><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="passwordconfirmation" placeholder="REPITE LA CONTRASEÑA">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar">
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, identa el código en las respuestas, sino, el código HTML no se ve. Y, argumenta tu respuesta. ¿Por qué crees que hay que poner un archivo en el `action`?  Si el código se ejecuta en el mismo archivo no hace falta ponerlo.

Comment: Ademas OP dijo que si ejecuta el codigo, porque le sale el mensaje que espera.. el problema es el query.